# Z = X+Y Functions of Two Continuous Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have

$f_X(x) = 3e^{−3x}$ for x > 0

$f_Y(y) = 2e^{−2y}$ for y > 0

$f_{XY}(x,y) = 6e^{-3x} e^{-2y}$
for 0 < x < ∞ and 0 < y < ∞

I know that X and Y are independent and I want to find:  $Z = X + Y$

This is what i have tried:
$$\int_0^∞  6e^{-3x} e^{-2(z-x)} \, dx = 6e^{−2*z}$$
and the right answer is $6e^{−2z}(1-e^{-z})$

Am i not getting the limits right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct integral is $\int_0^{z} 6e^{-3x} e^{-2(z-x)}dx$. (In your integral $z-x$ may be negative so that is not correct).